# Count Variable column wise in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a tableA

```
|Column1|Column2|Column3|
|NO     |NO     |YES    |
|YES    |YES    |NO     |
|NO     |NO     |NO     |
```

My requirement is to count the number of Yes or No per row and display the greatest (or equal to) of them. My sample output should be like:

```
|Column1|Column2|Column3|Answer
|NO     |NO     |YES    |No
|YES    |YES    |NO     |Yes
|NO     |NO     |NO     |No
```

I know i can use a where clause if my requirement was to count them column wise, but how do I get this to be done row wise?

Comment: have you try you?

Comment: If it is only a few columns, you can use a `CASE WHEN` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only 3 fixed columns then you can get expected result set by using `CASE` statement

```
SELECT 
  *,
  CASE
    WHEN Column1 = Column2 
    THEN Column1 
    WHEN Column1 = Column3 
    THEN Column1 
    WHEN Column2 = Column3 
    THEN Column2 
    ELSE NULL 
  END answer 
FROM
  demo a
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/ADI56259)

Answer (score 0):

Following query will work:

```
SELECT 
    c1,c2,c3,    
   (
     case when
       ROUND 
       (   
          (
            CHAR_LENGTH(concat_ws(" ",c1,c2,c3))
            - CHAR_LENGTH( REPLACE ( concat_ws(" ",c1,c2,c3), "NO", "") ) 
          ) / CHAR_LENGTH("NO")
       ) > ROUND 
       (   
          (
            CHAR_LENGTH(concat_ws(" ",c1,c2,c3))
            - CHAR_LENGTH( REPLACE ( concat_ws(" ",c1,c2,c3), "YES", "") ) 
          ) / CHAR_LENGTH("YES")
       )
        then 'NO'
        else 'YES'
        end
 )   
     AS Answer    
FROM t;
```